# Don`t open infoWindow with custom marker. (Google maps)

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I need to open an `infoWindow` on `customMarker`.

The InfoWindow is not opening. "Click" doesn't work on:

```
$google.maps.event.addDomListener(overlay, 'click', function () {
        console.log("test");
        iw.open(map, this);
        });
```

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON(jsonShops, function(places) {
    for (var i = 0, index = 0; i < places.shops.length; i++, index++) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLng(places.shops[i].lat, places.shops[i].lng);
        var overlay = new MarkerSOverlay(bounds, alphabet.charAt(index), map);

        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Simple",                
            position: bounds
        });


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(overlay, 'click', function () {
            console.log("test");
            iw.open(map, this);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `addDomListener` to `addListener`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'click', function () {
   console.log("test");
   iw.open(map, this);
});
```

`addListener` is for google.maps objects (like Markers), `addDomListener` is for DOM nodes.